# Is it possible to scan while running hostapd?

Tags: wifi, adhoc

I am using hostapd to create an adhoc WPA secured wifi network, everything is working fine.  From another machine I can connect with no issues.

However when hostapd is running the command:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

returns:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported
```

If I kill the hostapd process and bring up the wlan0 interface then scan works correctly and returns the ssids of nearby networks.

I want to be able to scan while hostapd is running.  How to do this?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This capability depends on your wireless chipset. Some support this and others do not.

Comment: What is this capability called? What would I have to look for to find a chipset that provides this functionality?